# IPHONE - detecting horizontal finger swipe on a UITableView cell

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have a UITableView with several cells. This table is to be scrolled vertically. So, vertical finger swipes will scroll the table.

Normally an horizontal finger swipe on a table will present an option to delete that cell, like it is on mail.

I would like to detect horizontal finger swipes on a cell and use this to trigger a method that will have the table row as a parameter, not to delete the cell.

How can this be done?

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is an implementation http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=532573

but as this changes a default ui behavior its not a very good idea

Comment: in fact, the swipe gesture is related to deleting the cell, but as the cell is a picture, I will present the user with a menu where he can choose if he want to replace the cell with a picture from the camera or from the library... in essence the cell will be deleted...

thanks. I will check the solution.

Comment: how would you manage to notify the rest of the cells of a swipe? suppose you show contents of a cell on swipe, you would want to hide contents in the non-swiped cells (maybe some other cell that was swiped before)